# How to speed up transposing a data.frame by group?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this `data.frame` with equal length groups (`id`)

```
id  |  amount 
--------------
 A  |   10   
 A  |   54   
 A  |   23   
 B  |   34   
 B  |   76    
 B  |   12
```

which I would like to transpose **by group** `id` to this:

```
 id |
----------------------
 A  | 10  |  54 | 23  
 B  | 34  |  76 | 12
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

I've previously used `reshape` and `dcast` but they are very slow indeed! (I have A LOT of data and would love to speed up this bottleneck)

Is there a better strategy? Using `data.table` or matrices?? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
# Little data.frame
df <- data.frame(id=c(2,2,2,5,5,5), amount=as.integer(c(10,54,23,34,76,12)))

# Not so little data.frame
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(sample(1:10000, 10000, replace=F),100), amount=as.integer(floor(runif(1000000, -100000,100000))))

# Create time variable
df$time <- ave(as.numeric(df$id), df$id, FUN = seq_along)

# The base R reshape strategy
system.time(df.reshape <-reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar="id", timevar="time"))
user  system elapsed 
6.36    0.31    6.69 

# The reshape2 dcast strategy
require(reshape2)
a <- system.time(mm <- melt(df,id.vars=c('id','time'),measure.vars=c('amount')))
b <- system.time(df.dcast <- dcast(mm,id~variable+time,fun.aggregate=mean))
a+b
user  system elapsed 
14.44    0.00   14.45
```

**UPDATE**
Using the fact that each group is equal in length you can use the `matrix`-function.

```
df.matrix <- data.frame(id=unique(df$id), matrix(df$amount, nrow=(length(unique(df$id))), byrow=T))
user  system elapsed 
0.03    0.00    0.03
```

*Note:* This method assumes that the data.frame is presorted by `id`.

Comment: Maybe you should provide an example that runs in less than two minutes ? :)

Comment: @juba - sorry about that, I've made it smaller! I'm eager to find something that will work for lots and lots of data. :)

Comment: It might be most efficient to not transpose. Any particular reason why you are doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem of `reshape`. `aggregate` from base should be able to handle this.

```
df.out <- aggregate(amount ~ id, data=df, c)
# running on the small data
#   id amount.1 amount.2 amount.3
# 1  2       10       54       23
# 2  5       34       76       12
```

Isn't this what you wanted?

---

Okay, seems like an adapted version of `DWin`'s solution is the fastest. However, the result will be ordered by `id`. If you don't want that, then `Aditya`'s seems to be the one to use.

Here are the functions and the benchmarking results:

- Using `aggregate`:

  ```
  AGG <- function() {
      df.agg <- aggregate(amount ~ id, data=df, c)
  }
  ```
- Using `Aditya`'s

  ```
  SEC <- function() {
      df.sec <- cbind(data.frame(id = unique(df$id)), 
              matrix(as.numeric(unlist(tapply(df$amount, df$id, identity))), 
              nrow = length(unique(df$id)), byrow = T))
  }
  ```
- Using modified version of `Dwin`'s:

  ```
  DWIN_M <- function() {
      df1 <- df[with(df, order(id)), ]
      idx <- df$id[!duplicated(df$id)]
      df.dwin <- cbind(data.frame(id=idx), 
                  as.data.frame(matrix(df1$amount, 
                  nrow=length(idx), byrow=TRUE)))
  }
  ```
- Benchmarking:

  ```
  require(rbenchmark)
  benchmark(AGG(), SEC(), DWIN_M(), replications=3, order="elapsed")

  #      test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
  # 3 DWIN_M()            3   4.175    1.000     4.148    0.000          0         0
  # 2    SEC()            3  17.568    4.208    17.449    0.016          0         0
  # 1    AGG()            3  24.529    5.875    24.306    0.044          0         0
  ```

Let me know if I've made any errors.

Comment: that took 6.436 seconds on my system

Comment: @Aditya, yes, `aggregate` is slower. of course, `tapply` is better here! If there were more than 1 `amount` column, `aggregate` makes more sense.

Comment: @Dwin, why did you delete the post? It seems to be really fast (except that the results will be sorted).

Comment: @Arun - Awesome work! But am I missing something or is aggregate NOT transposing the data?

Comment: @wije, seems fine to me, check my edit. I've added the result for the small `data.frame`.

Comment: @Arun - Wierd! I get this `'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ id    : num  2 5
 $ amount: int [1:2, 1:3] 45 34 66 71 99 22`

Comment: @Arun - Would you mind benchmarking this version of the matrix code: `df.matrix <- data.frame(id=unique(df$id), matrix(df$amount, nrow=(length(unique(df$id))), byrow=T))` It runs on 0.03s on the big df (presorted) on my computer.

Comment: @wije, of course this is faster, because you cleverly used one `data.frame` expression to get the matrix and no `cbind`. (About the aggregate, I've no idea why you get that output)

Comment: @wije, but you've to be careful to make sure that the `data.frame` is ordered by `id` before to use the `matrix` expression. Right?

Answer (score 2):

A matrix approach would use:

```
  system.time({ df.reshape <-matrix(df$amount, nrow=10000, byrow=TRUE); 
               rownames(df.reshape)<- df$id[1:10000]
             } )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.010   0.006   0.016
```

Answer (score 1):

try this out:

```
 dFrame<-data.frame(id = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3)),amount = c(10,54,23,34,76,12))
 newFrame<-cbind(data.frame(id = unique(dFrame$id)),matrix(as.numeric(unlist(tapply(dFrame$amount,dFrame$id,identity))),nrow=length(unique(dFrame$id)),byrow=T))
```

The bracketing might be off, i've tried to be careful - i don't have an R interpreter available at the moment

benchmark result based on the df sample code you provide:

```
  replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
   1            1   4.193        1     4.056    0.064          0         0
```

Comment: you can probably speed this up a bit more by caching the result of unique(dFrame$id)